# On a Mac, how to see a list of notifications that came from Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, notifications

Google Chrome can let a webpage show notifications as a system notification (of the OS).  Is there a way to see a list of the past notifications?

Comment: does that mean I have to install some third-party app (Growl) in order to see the notification that came out when I walked away to get a coffee?  that is somewhat weird

Comment: also, I just found out the app costs $3.99, which means $4. The reviews on the App store for that app is about 3 star